# What communication protocol does MySQL use?

Tags: mysql, protocols, communication

For example, when a web-browser connects to a web-server, it uses HTTP for a protocol at the application layer. But when a web-server connects to MySQL server, another database, what  application layer protocol is used for the request and response? Or have I misunderstood something? Thank you!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's simply called "MySQL protocol".

Refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/PAGE_PROTOCOL.html

Comment: Sorry. I never heard of such Application layer protocols. Is it a standard protocol? What about Postgres or MongoDB?

Comment: @MuraliMopuru I was also searching for the application protocols for common databases like MySQL and MongoDB and landed on this question. My understanding is, 'MySQL protocol' itself can be an application protocol, which builds upon the TCP/IP transport and network layer protocols. The 'MySQL protocol' resides on the same level as common application protocols such as 'HTTP', 'SMTP', just that it is not one of the RFC standards protocols. As mentioned in the book 'Computer Network: Top down approach', Skype uses its proprietary application protocol which also builds upon TCP/IP.