# Is it possible to use mysql proxy for query processing in front of microsoft sql server?

Tags: database, load-balancing, mysql-proxy

I want to use mysql proxy for processing queries trying to execute. I want to make this process available for all databases like mysql, ms sql server, oracle and ...
is it possible to use mysql proxy as base engine and connect these database from that? if no, is it possible to do this by making some little changes to mysql proxy source code?

Comment: Postgres' FDW (Foreign Data Wrapper) might be much better suited for this. Toss in [multicorn](http://multicorn.org/) and life just may be beautiful. If you throw in `unixodbc` into the mix there's really nothing you can't do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that i have to use other exisiting proxies and change them in order to get what I need

Answer (score 1):

You could use the standard external stored procedure support in the DBMS, but it would be difficult to map arbitrary queries to something meaningful.

Your are likely to be more successful implementing a lightweight parser as described in [MySQL Client/Server Protocol](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/client-server-protocol.html) and [What communication protocol uses MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860875/what-communication-protocol-uses-mysql).

Your preference that this can be done with 'some little changes' is likely not to be realistic. Expect a major job of the scale of ODBC to implement a generic SQL dialect translator.